# joomla protostar formfield width responsivness

Tags: cms, css, form

How is it possible to size formfield widths for Joomlas Protostar Template?

```
<field name="titel"
type="text"
label="COM_COMPONENT_TITEL_LABEL"
description="COM_COMPONENT_TITEL_DESC"
class="inputbox"
size="45"
required="false" />
```

I've tried different possibilities, but none of them are working.
class="inputbox span3", size="10", "input.span3", "inputbox.span3", size="span3"

thx, Perino

Comment: Protostar is for the front-end. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I know that Protostar is for the front-end. Im creating a formular with different input fields. These input fields should have different widths. One of these fields should be a textarea field. But this is displayed with the standard editor. How can I display the textarea box normal without editor?

Comment: What's the CSS for your formfield? Do you have a live demo we can look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following classes can be added to your input field in order to control the size:

```
class="inputbox input-mini"
class="inputbox input-small" 
class="inputbox input-medium"
class="inputbox input-large"
class="inputbox input-xlarge"
class="inputbox input-xxlarge"
```

The `size="45"` parameter seems to be overridden by the CSS class `.inputbox`, forcing the width to `206px`. Adding any of the classes above will solve this.